# Image positioning and orientation in reportlab pdfgen using canvas

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am been struggling with this from over 2 days now. I am using reportlab-4.0.4 and trying to add image on PDF using canvas. But no matter how I try, the image never goes to the coordinates I am expecting. The issue here is, I am not able to figure out any pattern since the image sometimes goes way up while sometimes it goes way down, depending on the position of the coordinates.

Our front end app sends the coordinates to sign and in backend (python) I am trying to place the signature image.

Here is my code.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
signed_pdf_tmp_file = io.BytesIO()
c = canvas.Canvas(signed_pdf_tmp_file, pagesize=page.mediabox)

c.drawImage(
    coordinate.draw_it,
    X,
    Y,
    width,
    height,
    anchor="c",
    mask="auto",
    preserveAspectRatio=True,
    showBoundary=False,
)
```

width and height are the width and height of the image uploaded by the user. X and Y are the coordinates of the image start on PDF (calculated on Angular side and sent).

Angular snippet

```
x1: Math.ceil(item.repositionedX1 / 96 * 72),
y1: Math.ceil(y1 / 96 * 72),
width: Math.ceil(item.width / 96 * 72),
height: Math.ceil(item.height / 96 * 72)
```

Initially the image was inverted. So I tried doing `c.scale(1, -1)`. This makes the image appear correctly but on wrong coordinates. I tried c.translate(X, Y), c.translate(X, Y + height) etc.
In some cases the image renders correctly, but its not consistent. Depending on where user has chose to sign and the size of the actual image, the placement varies. I am not able to find a specific formula to place it correctly irrespective of X, Y, height and width. The pdf can be multi page and image can be anywhere on any page.

Any help is welcome. I am now not able to think anything.